# leer un archivo txt y verificar si existe un dato en c++

Tags: c++

Buena tengo una consulta, tengo un archivo txt llamado "nombre.txt" en la cual tengo almacenado 3 nombres, pero mi duda es ¿como validar o verificar si un nombre ya existe en el archivo?. Lo que busco es solo leer el archivo y validar si el nombre existe o no

Este es mi archivo "nombre.txt"

```
Nombre: Jose
Nombre: Pedro
Nombre: Maria
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string  dato;
char band = 'F';
ifstream fichero;



dato = "jose";



fichero.open("nombre.txt", ios::in);

while(!fichero.eof()){


if(fichero == dato){
   band = 'V';

}

}

if(band =='F'){

cout<<"el nombre no existe";

}

else if(band =='V'){

  cout<<"el nombre ya existe";
}

return 0;
}
```

Claro me salio error en el código, pero es mas o menos lo que estoy intentado. Solo busco leer el archivo y verificar si el nombre existe o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una comparación como la siguiente, acá obtienes los valores separados por el espacio que se van asignando a la variable b, con cada línea nueva que leas del texto se va haciendo la comparación con la cadena de búsqueda que entres por consola, si se encuentra se termina la lectura, sino te salen un mensaje de "No encontrado"

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  std::ifstream indata("nombre.txt");
  std::string line;
  std::string search;

  std::cout << "Busca un nombre\n";
  std::cin >> search;

  while (std::getline(indata, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string a, b;

    if (!(iss >> a >> b)) { break; }

    if (search == b) {
      std::cout << "El registro fue encontrado!\n";
      return 0;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "El registro no fue encontrado\n";

  return 0;
```

Comment: Gracias empezare a leer tu codigo y a entenderlo. Saludos!

Comment: Una pregunta en caso de que el archivo no fuera nombre sino numero, el codigo fuera distinto cierto? ando practicando

Comment: disculpa por lo novato

Comment: Pues si necesitas hacer operaciones numéricas si tienes que cambiarlo, si solo estas revisando la existencia de un dato no necesitas cambiarlo