# ¿como buscar una palabra en un fichero en C?

Tags: c, archivo, buscador, cuenta-usuario, filereader

estoy haciendo un proyecto para la materia de fundamentos de programación, y lo único que me falta es una función en la que el usuario ingrese una palabra, y luego se busque en el archivo si existe esa palabra, pero no se como hacerlo, hice el siguiente código que se me ocurrió pero no me arroja nada:

```
void consultarUsuario(){
system("cls");
char palabra[100],buffer[100];

printf("ingresa el nombre de usuario\n");
scanf("%s", palabra);
FILE *f;
f = fopen("./db_boletos/baseprueba.dat", "r");
//fgets(texto,100,f);
while (feof(f)==0)      
{
    fgets(buffer,100,f);
    if (palabra==buffer)        
    {
        printf("%s", buffer);

        break;
    }
    
}

fclose(f);
```

}

Lo que trato de hacer es una especie de busqueda de usuario, entonces necesito que no tome palabras que coincidan, por ejemplo, aunque exista "pepe2" solo quiero que se tome en cuenta si existe "pepe"

GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA :)

Comment: El programa no se comporta como espera porque: 1) al leer con `fgets(buffer,100,f)` obtiene una cadena de 100 caracteres o hasta el final de la linea (si la línea tiene menos de 100 caracteres esto podria partirle palabras). 2) Debe dividir la linea en palabras (utilice `strtok()` para partir en `palabritas`) 3) La comparación `palabra==buffer` compara las direcciones de los punteros de inicio de las cadenas. Deberia reemplazar ese predicado por `strcmp(palabra,palabrita)==0` incluyendo `string.h`

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de cómo luce el archivo .dat?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [leer un archivo txt y verificar si existe un dato en c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457286/leer-un-archivo-txt-y-verificar-si-existe-un-dato-en-c)

Comment: @MauricioOrtega No creo que sea un duplicado, son lenguajes diferentes.

Comment: Seria bueno que compartieras el archivo de de prueba también, así te podríamos dar una respuesta mas completa. Con lo que veo de momento, te recomendaría que leyeras usando `fscanf`. Toma nota que para comparar arrays de caracteres no se usa `==`, tienes que usar `strcmp`.

Comment: Así lucen los registros en mi archivo .dat

jesus2
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 2
TOTAL A PAGAR: 400.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 64.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200

medina
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 2
TOTAL A PAGAR: 400.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 64.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200

jesus
el rey leon3, 10:00am-13:00pm
CANTIDAD DE BOLETOS: 3
TOTAL A PAGAR: 600.000000
IVA (INCLUIDO): 96.000000
PRECIO DE BOLETO: 200

Comment: de casualidad podía darme un ejemplo de codigo? Mauricio Ortega esque no entendí muy bien como sería :c